# How to reduce duplicate components which will only be showing one at a time on ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

As you can see from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlzoprzowm), there are multiple panels but only a single panel can be expanded at a time, however the `<Content />` got mounted multiple times, is there a way to only use a single `<Content />` across these multiple panels ?

Comment: Of course there is a way. Make content render the panels you want. Content should handle the active (opened) panel. You can make it dynamic if you want by passing meta info about each panel as props to content. Then content just renders the panels you pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering to avoid multiple mounting of your `<Content />`  component. Your render should look like this:

```
render() {
const { expanded } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="App">
    {["panel 1", "panel 2", "panel 3", "panel 4", "panel 5", "panel 6"].map(
      panel => (
        <ExpansionPanel
          expanded={expanded === panel}
          onChange={this.handleChange(panel)}
        >
          <ExpansionPanelSummary>{panel}</ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            {expanded === panel ? <Content from={panel} /> : null}
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      )
    )}
  </div>
);
}
```

Use the condition `expanded===panel` to mount only when required.

Here  is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xr31llnypo

Comment: Conditional rendering can be done at <ExpansionPanelDetails>

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional rendering:

```
   <ExpansionPanel
          expanded={expanded === panel}
          onChange={this.handleChange(panel)}
        >
              {expanded === panel && 
                  <ExpansionPanelDetails >
                    <Content from={panel} />
                  </ExpansionPanelDetails>
              }
    </ExpansionPanel>
```

More about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html